# Form Class, Keep getting a "System.StackOverflowException" on a simple code test

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inheritance

I have been trying to implement and adapt my coding style moving form more of a procedural programming style but have been running into problems, when trying to run another class working with the systems registry. Furthermore the code works fine in the main class. P.S I come form a scripting background.

**Code Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll**

I have cut down the code from the main application to make it easier to find the problem.

**Main Form Class:**

```
public partial class Form1test : Form
{
    // An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' 
    // occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
    public Form1test() 
    {
        TestClass lsr = new TestClass();
        lsr.chkRegAct();
        InitializeComponent();
    }  
}
```

**TestClass:**

```
class TestClass : Form1test
{
   //rest of code
}
```

Comment: It's not clear why TestClass inherits from Form1test.  It can probably stand on it's own.

Comment: `TestClass` shouldn't inherit from `Form1test`. You get an infinite recursion with `TestClass lsr = new TestClass();` in the ctor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TestClass` is derived from `Form1Test`.

You create a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates a new `TestClass` which results to calling the constructor of base class (`Form1Test`) which generates .....

**StackOverflowException due to lot of function calls caused by infinite recursion.**

Answer (score 3):

Due to the inheritance chain *TestClass : Form1test*. Calling the TestClass Constructor creates infinite recursion.